# Google Calendar: Sync recently created calendar within my Google account

Tags: oauth, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, android-calendar

I just played around with the Google Calendar Java API within my Scala Webframework and managed to create a new calendar programatically. After that, I create a new event within that calendar.

My problem is, that the event in the new calendar does not seem to be synced with my client devices (my tablet). However, if I create an event in my "primary" calendar, I immediately see the event on all of my devices.

If I go to https://www.google.com/calendar/syncselect, the recently created calendar is checked. So actually I would expect all events to be synced on my devices.

I'm using the JAVA API within a Scala context:

```
def addCalendar(serviceCalendar: com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar): com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar = {

    val calendar = new Calendar()
    calendar.setSummary("test calendar")
    serviceCalendar.calendars().insert(calendar).execute()
  }
 //...



 //code fragment where a new event is inserted into an existing calendar
 val credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(token.get.value)
 val calendar = Auth.getCalendarService(credential)
 //create a new test calendar
 val testCalendar = addCalendar(calendar)
 val event = createEvent

 //insert new event into "primary" calendar.
 calendar.events().insert("primary", event).execute()
 //insert event into the new calendar
 calendar.events().insert(testCalendar.getId(), event).execute()
```

Both events appear in the Google Calendar web interface. However only the event in the "primary" calendar is synced.

If I look into the "calendar list" of my Android (Samsung S Planner, Android 4.3.) application, I don't see the recently created calendar as "in sync". (The primary calendar is marked as in sync!).

So I guess this is the reason why I see the "primary event" but not the other one. But actually I would expect Google to send some kind of push notification that a new calendar has been added to the account.

Can I enforce that programatically? Or is it simply a matter of time?

Comment: You can check the watch method of calendar list(https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/watch) for push notifications. check this link on how to set up for push notifications for the resources https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push

Answer (score 1):

Syncselect only influences iCalendar, iOS and other CalDAV clients. It's not used for Android. In there the toggle for calendar syncing is on the device and AFAIK needs to be done manually.

Comment: Is this a problem of Android or could the problem be solved by using Google's CalDAV API?

Comment: The "manual sync only" model seems to be true somehow. So if I hit "sync" in my calendar application I know see my test calendar. However I still don't see the event I've created.

Comment: Is the event in the past?

Comment: Actually it is in the "present". So when I create the event I use some kind of DateTime.now. So basically the current server time.

Comment: do those inserts succeed? Can you see the events in the web calendar?

Comment: Yes, I see both events. The one that I created in the primary calendar and the second event I created in my new calendar. Both are visible in the web calendar

Comment: Can you check whether this also happens with the official Google Calendar app? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar&hl=en

Comment: Yes, it also happens with the original Google calendar. The event in the primary calendar is immediately visible on my tablet whereas the event in the recently created calendar is not shown.

Comment: In the official app you can go into the sandwich menu -> settings -> show more -> tap on the calendar name and tick off "sync"